# Effective way to use GET and PUT in the same method for REST based API Testing using Groovy

Tags: json, rest, groovy, automated-tests

I am automating testing the HTTP response code for a PUT JSON request for REST based API using groovy and I am trying to find a effective way to minimize the multiple calls to the Service. Currently I am:

1. Calling the service using `JsonSlurper` to get a list of items
2. Using the `itemId` from the initial request to make the PUT Request using `openConnection()`.

Can anyone suggest a better alternative that can avoid the multiple calls being down?

```
public void updateItemV1()
{

    //get full list of items    
    def rawitems = JsonSlurper().parseText("$baseUrlItem/v1/items ".toURL().text)

    def items = rawitems as items

    //get the itemid and clientid of the first item in the list
    def itemId = items.content.get(0).ItemId
    def clientId = items.content.get(0).ClientId

    //Update Data
    def item_updReq = [
            ItemId                    : itemId,
            ItemState                 : "DRAFT",
            ClientId                  : clientId,
            ]

    //verify item is updated
    def getupditmUrl = "$baseUrlItem/v1/items/$itemId".toURL()
    getupditmUrl.openConnection().with {
        requestMethod = "PUT"
        doOutput = true
        setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
        outputStream.withWriter("UTF-8"){ new StreamingJsonBuilder(it, item_updReq)}

        //verify response code
        verifyTrue(responseCode == 200)
    }

}
```

Comment: If you are asking how to design a REST endpoint to allow a single call to partially update a resource, then look into the PATCH HTTP verb.  The "merge-patch+json" format is one implementation of this.  It will be tricky to implement this in Java with POJOs though since there is no distinction between null and undefined.

Comment: Hi Jon. Thanks for your input. I am trying to verify the response of a PUT request. Just wanted to find out if I can have the GET and PUT within the openConnection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not make multiple HTTP requests from a single `openConnection()`.

> Each HttpURLConnection instance is used to make a single request but the underlying network connection to the HTTP server may be transparently shared by other instances.

From: [HttpURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

On a side note, I suggest you use a different HTTP client API if possible. Any of the below will provide a more fluent and readable API than the native JDK URLConnection classes.

1. [HttpBuilder for Groovy](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki)
2. [Spring's RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html)
3. [Jersey Client](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html)
4. [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)

Comment: Thanks Jon. A friend of mine suggested HttpBuilder too. Think I will try that.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer if it answered your question sufficiently.